# Pandas - Replacing data frame value from a variable and not hard coded

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove the strings in my column 2 which exists in my column 1. For example:

> Column 1: aBcdefGH
>   Column 2:  aBcdefGHxxxxxzzzaBcdefGH

I only want to retain ***xxxxxzzz*** since ***aBcdefGH*** exists in Column 1. I have tried to do this via replace method like below to no avail:

```
df['Column 2'] = df['Column 2'].replace(df['Column 1'], "")
```

I even tried to iterate it but it does not work as well:

```
for i in df:
    rem_str = df['Column 1']
    df['Column 2'] = df['Column 2'].replace(rem_str, "")
```

Any ideas on how to make this work? Thanks

Comment: What is desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going right, just use `regex=True`:

```
df['Column 2'].replace(df1['Column 1'], "", regex=True, inplace=True)

# xxxxxzzz
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `list Comprehension` (Assuming no nan's and data is clean):

```
[y.replace(x,'') for x,y in zip(df['Column 1'], df['Column 2'])]
```

Comment: @chmscrbbrfck Glad to help.